# How to add multiple checks of OS for a package in puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

I have mixture of CentOS , 5.8, 5.7, 6.1, 6.3 , 4.7 Ubuntu, Debian, servers with me. I want all of them to have nrpe installed on them. the problem i am facing is that when i write puppet code to ensure the packe nrpe, it works fine on Centos 6+ , but when it runs on centos 5.8, the package name there is nrpe-nagio, and not nrpe.. I tried to do this in this way, but unable to perform the required checks.

```
package { "nrpe":
    ensure => "installed",
        name => $operatingsystem ? {
   Ubuntu => "nagios-nrpe-server",
   CentOS => "nrpe",
{
/^5/: {
package { "nagios-nrpe":
    ensure => "installed", }
        }
}

   Debian => "nagios-nrpe-server",
    }
}
```

How can i have nested checks for what i need?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline, nested case statements are a bad way to do this, and it's actively discouraged in Puppet (see [Puppet Lint documentation](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/selector_inside_resource/)).

The better way is this (I've guessed with `$::lsbdistrelease` as I don't have a RH system to-hand - you should run `facter` to determine the correct fact that gives you the major version).

```
$nrpe_package = $::osfamily ? {
  'Debian' => 'nagios-nrpe-server'
  'RedHat' => $::lsbdistrelease ? {
    '5'     => 'nagios-nrpe',
    default => 'nrpe',
  }
  default => 'nrpe',
}

package { 'nrpe':
  ensure => installed,
  name   => $nrpe_package,
}
```

Explanation (links to Puppet Lint where appropriate):

- [Set the variable outside of the package definition](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/selector_inside_resource/)
- [Include defaults for both case statements](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/case_without_default/)
- [Prefix top-level namespaces with `::`](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/variable_scope/)
- [Use single quotes for strings that don't have variables within them](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/double_quoted_strings/)
- Use hierarchical/nested cases appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You can use facter and some if/else conditions to tell Puppet which class you want to apply to each version of CentOS.

Example : http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#case

(Just use your OS version instead of the OS in the example provided).